# In-place ("Quick-Assist" or something easier) source code modifier?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse already has very impressive and useful what I call "source code modifiers" (please suggest a better name).

For example, it has "Quick Fix", "Word Completion", "Externalize Strings" and other functions that modify source code via menu (or key-combination).

Now, I am looking to add **my own** "source code modifier" function: I would like to:

1. Highlight (select) an arbitrary string.
2. Right-click on it
3. Invoke a menu item that would "translate" that string to a different string, using a function that I wrote (preferably in Java). Similar to "Quick Fix" or "Replace With" currently on the default context menu.

Is this possible in Eclipse?

If so, what do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'translate'? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve, maybe there is a simpler solution..

Comment: @Deepak Azad Thanks. I want to take, for example, variable names of the form `old_c_style_naming_convents` and automatically convert them to `modernJavaStyleNamingConvents`. I already wrote the Java code that does that (it's a simple method), but I don't know how to hook it up to Quick Assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:**

The quick assist will have to modify the [AST](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) of the Java code. Essentially you will have to replace a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName` node with one that you want.

**The long answer:**

The `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickAssistProcessors` extension point enables you to contribute your own Java code quick assists.

To create a new extension for the extension point you need to first provide the required extension in the plugin.xml. For example, JDT defines the following processor

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickAssistProcessors">
      <quickAssistProcessor
            name="%defaultQuickAssistProcessor"
            class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.QuickAssistProcessor"
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.correction.QuickAssistProcessor">
      </quickAssistProcessor>
   </extension>
```

(For a description of the individual attributes, please refer to the extension point documentation)

Then you need to create the class that implements the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.IQuickAssistProcessor` interface, and modify the AST in this class. (This class is the same as the one you specified while declaring the extension)

**Supplying the right IJavaCompletionProposal**

JDT provides the following default implementations for correction proposals that can be used to contribute quick fixes and quick assists.

- ChangeCorrectionProposal
- CUCorrectionProposal
- ASTRewriteCorrectionProposal

If you use an ASTRewrite, you should create an ASTRewriteCorrectionProposal.

**ASTView Plugin**

This is something that will help you visualize the AST of a Java source file http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I don't know whether I can expect something better. But I must admit that from here it looks quite involved & cumbersome. I was hoping for something less complex. I will have to explore this AST thing when I have more time, but for now +1. You will receive the accept+50 if an answer that allows me to implement what I want **quicker** isn't posted.

Comment: Actually I should thank you, as your question made me realize that the documentation to contribute a quick assist does not exist yet and that I need to add to JDT help :-)

Comment: AST can be a bit tricky to learn, and if you have more such 'quick assists' in mind I think you should try that. (I can help you if you get stuck somewhere). However, if this is a one off thing, I would look for alternate approaches e.g. using regex to find the matches in and then replacing those matches using the code you have written.

Answer (score 1):

The right name is '[Quick Assist](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-quickassist.htm)'. You have to write some code to create your Quick Assists.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like what I need. What kind of code do I write, where do I places it and how do I hook it up to my Eclipse?